# Generalized harmonic numbers and Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta-function

- The $n$-th harmonic number is defined as
  $$
  H_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k},
  $$
  and the generalized harmonic numbers are defined by
  $$
  H_{n}^{(m)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^m}.
  $$
- It is known result that
  $$
  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{n^3}=\frac{5}{4}\zeta(4).
  $$
  Here $\zeta(n)$ denotes [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

I conjecture that
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(2)}}{n^2}=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(4).
$$

Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: This is a special case of Section 4.12 of Cornel Ioan Vălean’s book *(Almost) Impossible
Integrals, Sums, and Series* (2019).

Comment: the general case with power $n^a$ in the denominator is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3801174/87355

Comment: One approach: https://mathoverflow.net/q/304061

Comment: Updated fr the odd case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This is not a proof.*

$$S_p=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{p}\frac{H_{n}^{(2)}}{n^2}$$
$$S_p=\frac{\left(H_p^{(2)}\right){}^2}{2}-\frac{H_p^{(4)}}{2}-\frac{\psi
    ^{(3)}(p+1)}{6}+\frac{\pi ^4}{90}$$
Expanded as series
$$S_p=\frac{7 \pi ^4}{360}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6 p}+\frac{6+\pi ^2}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Now, if you consider
$$T_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(2k)}}{n^{2k}}$$ you generate

$$T_k= a_k\, \zeta(4k)$$ where the coefficients are
$$\left\{\frac{7}{4},\frac{13}{12},\frac{703}{691},\frac{14527}{144
   68},\frac{524354}{523833},\frac{3546333857}{3545461365},\frac{
   6785975897}{6785560294},\frac{30837755428255}{30837284164868}
   \right\}$$

As @Notamathematician commented, the numerators correspon to sequence $A348830$ in $OEIS$. Sequence $A348829$ gives the  difference between numerator and denominator.

**Edit**

Interesting is the odd case

$$U_k=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(2k+1)}}{n^{2k+1}}=\frac 12 \big(\zeta(2k+1)\big)^2+ \,\zeta(2(2k+1)\big) $$

Comment: You can mention A348830.

Comment: @Notamathematician. Sorry ! I did not search. I shall edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: See also A348829 (difference between numerator and denominator).

Comment: WolframAlpha gives $\frac{1}{2}(\zeta(k)^2 + \zeta(2k))$ for general case.

Comment: @Notamathematician. I suppose that I was sleeping. Thanks again.